# Redirect on login / register page when proceed to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, guest-checkout

On my website I have 2 env; sandbox and pre-production.

On sandbox env I can see a normal behaviour, if i'm not logged in and i try to proceed the checkout as guest from the cart after adding an item. I'm having a modal that appears to login or register

[image: popup]

But on my pre-production environment, this popup doesn't appear, and instead it's reloading the current page

[image: reload]

On both environment, I've setup the option Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options and set Allow Guest Checkout to "No"

Comment: Any error on console or magento log files?

Comment: None sadly :/  it should only be triggered with a js action so I also checked the console but nothing special.

Comment: Have you run all the commands again like upgrade, deploy and compilation and then check.

Comment: Yes Indeed but that doesn't make any change, the page keeps loading the cart again.